# Gulp tasks miss the file I specifically saved and builds all the rest

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I setup gulp on a remove server and got tasks for js and scss that have watcher on. Whenever I save a file in my text editor, it gets sftp upladed to the server, where the watcher sees the file change and starts the task, but almost every time, the compiled files misses the file i just saved.

What i mean by that, is that i have multiple _example.scss that are all include in a main.scss, it will compile and output all the styles in every _example.scss file, apart from the one i just saved.

This happens for both the JS as well as SASS task, but only when the watcher start the task. If I stop and start Gulp, all files as compiled.

Here's the gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var gulpif = require('gulp-if');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var watchify = require('watchify');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var transform = require('vinyl-transform');
var streamify = require('gulp-streamify');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Same as browserify task, but will also watch for changes and re-compile.
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
gulp.task('js', function() {
    return browserify('./js/main.js')
        .transform(babelify, {presets: ["es2015"]})
        .bundle()
        .on('error', function(e) {
            gutil.log(e);
        })
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(streamify(uglify()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/build'));
});

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Compile LESS stylesheets.
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
gulp.task('styles', function() {
  return gulp.src('./scss/main.scss')
    .pipe(sass.sync().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('./scss/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
  gulp.watch('./js/components/*.js', ['js']);
  gulp.watch('./js/*.js', ['js']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'js', 'watch']);
```

To make it clear, I get no error from terminal. My output looks like this.

```
[15:45:50] Using gulpfile /example/path/to/gulpfile.js
[15:45:50] Starting 'styles'...
[15:45:50] Starting 'js'...
[15:45:50] Starting 'watch'...
[15:45:50] Finished 'watch' after 17 ms
[15:45:50] Finished 'styles' after 221 ms
[15:45:53] Finished 'js' after 2.86 s
[15:45:53] Starting 'default'...
[15:45:53] Finished 'default' after 4.96 μs
```

Comment: When you say that gulp "misses" your file, you mean that the styles task completes but the compiled css includes the previous version of the sass partial you just edited?

Comment: No. I mean, it seems to save all other files except this one, it ignores it, as if it does not exist as all. It's as if the FTP transfer is deleting the file, it thinks it's being changed, they build while the file is missing and then the file gets written to the server again :/ . Any ideas?

Comment: So then the partial you saved is not included in the compiled css at all? How is the gulp task being triggered? Is gulp.watch running on the server? If so, I would have to guess that this actually is an issue with timing regarding how FTP is writing to the server.

Comment: Yea, it's as if it's not on the server. The task is being triggered when a file is changed in the directory, but I guess that can also be the file being 'deleted' before the new one gets uploaded through FTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those coming here looking for an answer, you can refer to the answer of this question [gulp.watch() not working with ftp update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24979799/gulp-watch-not-working-with-ftp-update)

TL;DR The FTP transfer protocol first sends a packet to confirm it can send the rest of the file. That initial packet triggers the GULP task and it compiles a file that's currently empty. The slower the network the longer it would take for the transfer. The 'fix' is to delay a task for a certain amount of time before compiling your files. I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-wait but I'm sure others can do the trick.

Comment: While it would probably work most of the time, a manual wait time is somewhat hacky solution, depending on the network speed & filesize, as you said. The file upload may not be complete by the time the task starts. Is there possibly another trigger that could be used to start the gulp task, abandoning gulp's watch function altogether?

Comment: Technical yes, the problem we have is that we detect the beginning of a file upload and not its completion. Assuming that you have the gulp running the server you upload the file, instead of using gulp watcher to check file changes you use a python library like https://github.com/joh/when-changed  which is pretty much like gulp file watcher but triggers on file upload completion and you use that to trigger the gulp command like `when-changed -r /var/www/website/css/internal /var/www/website/js/internal -c gulp`. Ever more so, you could create a bash script to the exact same effect.